# How to set 'column-primary' to backoffice 2nd column by default

Tags: columns

I'm customizing the way custom posts are displayed in the backoffice.
I'm trying to shift the section that appear on hover (I'm refering to the four buttons *Edit, Quick edit, Trash, Preview*) in the first column to the second one.
The reason is that the section, even if is hidden, takes up space vertically.
It seems that the edit section is assigned to the column that is signed with the class *column-primary*, so I'd like to assign that class to the second column by default
Actually is like this:
[image: how it is]
This is how should be:
[image: how should be]

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

---

UPDATE

I've seen that this function is managed by the file */wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php*

[image]

I've tried changing default primary column to line 1077 by assigning the value "Titolo" because it is the value reported in *data-colname* when inspecting the page

Does anyone know where the mistake is?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your screenshot didn’t seem to work. Can you try again? I’m not clear what you’re referring to.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fWgVls2deD46afus89cpjGcvQ2PmZO8N/view?usp=sharing
thanks Jacob, probably I can't upload gifs

Comment: pleease! XD it is a recurring problem for the projects I develop